What is ruling of taking picture when person passed away
There is a trend for people take snaps of miyat when they pass away to send someone who’s aboard and cannot see passing one at last moment. Mostly in state of funeral or when they pass away.
What is Islamic ruling as mobile is 20+ years technology with camera. All I know pictures are not allowed but to what extend?
